# Rotation of Continous curve is non self intersecting

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry

Let $f$ be the path traces from a continuous not-self intersecting curve from the center of a disc to its boundary.  Define rotation $F$ of $f$ pointwise by
$$
F(t,\theta)\triangleq 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos f_1(t) \\  
\sin f_2(t) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\,
,\theta \in [0,2\pi),
$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the components of the curve $f$.

Under what conditions will $F$ be injective from $[0,1]\times [0,2\pi)$ into the dist $Ball_1(0)$ within $\mathbb{R}^2$.